# Showing a number is not an algebraic integer

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I've been thinking about how to show $\zeta = (-1 + i\sqrt{3})/4$ is not an algebraic integer. I'm not sure how to proceed with a contradiction, because I don't see how to proceed if I assume it's the root of an arbitrary polynomial. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't it work to calculate the minimal polynomial and observe that it's not monic?

Comment: Additionally, $\zeta$ is just half a primitive third root of unity.

Comment: How would I find the minimal polynomial i.e. how do I know it will be quadratic and not anything else?

Comment: I understand it now, thank you!

Comment: it is a root of $P(x) = (x-\zeta)(x-\bar{\zeta}) = x^2 - 2x \, Re(\zeta) + |\zeta|^2 = x^2 + x/2 + \frac{1}{4}$. Clearly $P(x)$ is an irreducible monic polynomial of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ but it is not in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, hence $\zeta$ isn't algebraic.

Comment: @MJD I think that's not enough... To show $\zeta$ is not an algebraic integer, you'd have to show it's not the root of -any- monic polynomial in $\mathbb Z$ right?

Comment: But you know that any polynomial of which it is a root is multiple of the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @cat if $\zeta$ is a root of $P$ and $Q$ then it is a root of $gcd(P,Q)$ so that $deg(gcd(P,Q)) \ge 1$ and if $P$ is irreducible then $gcd(P,Q) = c\ P$. Hence the minimal polynomial (the only monic irreducible polynomial whose $\zeta$ is a root) is well-defined.

Comment: @MJD, yes that's correct and I see now, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

If $\zeta$ were an algebraic integer, then so is $\bar\zeta$ (why?). But then $\zeta + \bar \zeta = -\frac12$ would also be an algebraic integer (why?), which is a contradiction since the rational algebraic integers are just the integers.

Comment: in my opinion the why? is more about $\zeta + \bar{\zeta}$ is an algebraic integer

Comment: true; my (why?) is just a small thing.

Answer (score 1):

The trace of any algebraic integer must be a rational integer, but if we view $\zeta$ as an element of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ its trace is
$$ \mathrm{tr}(\zeta)=\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{4}+\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{4}=-\frac{1}{2}$$